# iPad HTML5 Video tag list and scrolling issue

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, html5-video

I am building cross platform application based on PhoneGap.
I am testing this app on iPad, I am using AngularJS.

I have created a list of media files using `ng-repeat` as below:

```
<div ng-repeat="media in mediaArray" style="width:200px; height:200px;">

     <img ng-src="{{media.imgSrc}}" 
          ng-hide="media.isVideo" 
          style="width:200px; height:200px;"
          >

     <video id="video{{media.id}"
            ng-show="media.isVideo"
            postersrc="test.png" 
            poster-src  <!-- Directive for poster source fix -->   
            controls 
            style="width:200px; height:200px;"
            >
            <source type="video/mp4" 
                    videosrc="{{media.videoUrl}}"
                    video-src  <!-- Directive for video source fix -->   
                    >
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.                    
     </video>
</div>
```

In my list I have images and video files.
I am able to see the list and also able to play the video files.

But problem is that, When I play any of the video then I am not able to scroll the list, scrolling works till I don't play any video once video is played scrolling does not work at all. what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div ng-repeat="media in mediaArray" ng-controller="ScrollController" style="width:200px; height:200px;">

     <img ng-src="{{media.imgSrc}}" 
          ng-hide="media.isVideo" 
          style="width:200px; height:200px;"
          >

     <video id="video{{media.id}"
            ng-show="media.isVideo"
            postersrc="test.png" 
            poster-src  <!-- Directive for poster source fix -->   
            controls 
            style="width:200px; height:200px;"
            >
            <source type="video/mp4" 
                    videosrc="{{media.videoUrl}}"
                    video-src  <!-- Directive for video source fix -->   
                    >
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.                    
     </video>
</div>
```

Script for controller

```
angular.module('anchorScrollExample', [])
.controller('ScrollController', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll',
  function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
    $scope.gotoBottom = function() {
      // set the location.hash to the id of
      // the element you wish to scroll to.
      $location.hash('bottom');

      // call $anchorScroll()
      $anchorScroll();
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have fixed it by adding div on top of video.

Comment: @A_user okay, answer your question it will be helpful for others